# keyboard shortcuts lost on iOS 8 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, iphone, ios

After up grading to iOS 8 i lost ALL my customized "keyboard shortcuts"... be it over a hundred of them.

I spent ages setting them mostly for work and now have NONE. Tried upgrading to the latest update iOS 8.0.2 but still none.

Because of this issue I have not upgraded the 2 iPads and one other iPhone 5s to latest software - and they all still have my customized keyboard shortcuts

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try to sync with iCloud to restore them ?

Answer (score 1):

It has been reported that upgrading iCloud to iCloud Drive corrects the issue and makes the shortcut both reappear and sync properly.

If that doesn't work (or if you have iCloud Drive already on), try rebooting your iPhone.